# Does Activesync certificate authentication replace a password, or act as 2 factor?

Tags: tls, certificates, mobile, exchange

I am looking at Activesync authentication and want to know if

- Certificate Authentication ignores a client username and password

or

- Certificate Authentication requires a username and password

For what it's worth, Android Activesync client setup requires a username and Password to proceed even when a certificate is installed

And Exchange server offers 3 different modes of authenticating:

[image]

In Activesync, is the certificate optional, or does it provide value to the password authentication?  (e.g. mutual auth TLS/prevent MITM)